# Arabic text issue on Mac using Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome, pdf, pdf.js

[Screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcLCr.png)

Code:

```
<div id="pdf"></div>

<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        var thePdf = null,
            scale = 2.5,
            base64pdf = atob('{{ $pdf }}');

        pdfjsLib.disableWorker = true;
        
        pdfjsLib.getDocument({data: base64pdf}).promise.then(function(pdf) {
            thePdf = pdf;
            viewer = document.getElementById('pdf');
            
            for(page = 1; page <= pdf.numPages; page++) {
                canvas = document.createElement("canvas");    
                canvas.className = 'pdf-page-canvas';         
                viewer.appendChild(canvas);            
                renderPage(page, canvas);
            }
        });

        function renderPage(pageNumber, canvas) {
            thePdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function(page) {
                viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: scale });
                canvas.height = viewport.height;
                canvas.width = viewport.width;          
                page.render({canvasContext: canvas.getContext('2d'), viewport: viewport});
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

File: https://easyupload.io/iclwni

The text is not connected together.

Is there a method to add/change the font or to convert the page into an image and add it to the canvas so that the browser doesn't manipulate the text?